# Why these two constructors become different, after I change its prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I defined a constructor like

`function Person(name) {this.name = name}`,

and create a new object `var p1 = new Person("Peter")`.

After that, I change the prototype of the constructor as `Person.prototype = {species: "human"}`, I found `p1.species` is `undefined`. However, if I create a new object like `p2 = new Person("John")`. `p2.species` is `"human"`.

```js
function Person(name) {this.name = name}

var p1 = new Person("Peter")

Person.prototype = {species: "human"}
console.log(p1.species)

var p2 = new Person("John")
console.log(p2.species)
```

After further investigating, I found

1. `p1.constructor === p2.constructor` is `false`
2. `p2.constructor === Person` is `false`

I would like to ask, how these two objects' constructors become different. (especially why `p1` does not have the prototype property `species`) Furthermore, how to explain point 2 above, while `p2` is created using function `Person`. (If so, why `p2` has the prototype property `species`)?

I tested these codes in Chrome console.

Thank you

Comment: Do not overwrite the prototype. Instead, write `Person.prototype.species = "human";`.

Comment: Well, the `.constructor` property is usually part of the prototype object. Your object has none (only the one that it inherits from `Object.prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't overwrite the prototype, but add a single key instead:

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var p1 = new Person("Peter");
Person.prototype.species = "human";
var p2 = new Person("John");
console.log(p1.species, p2.species);
console.log(p1 instanceof Person, p2 instanceof Person);
```

Comment: I knew it is not the proper way to create object. I just wish to know how it would happen